# Facebook Graph API for iPhone -- Cancel Button Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, graph, webview

I'm currently using the Facebook Graph API to log a user in and post to their wall... which works great. The issue I'm having is for the user that wants to retreat... and not log in. Basically, the "Cancel" button next the the "Login" button in the webView doesn't work properly (Facebook's fault) and I'm forced to include a "Close" button on the bottom.

Here is my problem: My code that opens the login webView seems to override anything I have in the .xib. My "Close" button I want to include at the bottom will not appear. Any idea why?

Currently (from an existing tutorial), the Facebook login is appearing with the following code:

```
- (void)authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:(id)anObject andSelector:(SEL)selector andExtendedPermissions:(NSString *)extended_permissions andSuperView:(UIView *)super_view {

    self.callbackObject = anObject;
    self.callbackSelector = selector;

    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch", facebookClientID, redirectUri, extended_permissions];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    CGRect webFrame = [super_view frame];

    webFrame.origin.y = 20;
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];    
    self.webView = aWebView;

    [webView loadRequest:request];  
    [super_view addSubview:webView];

}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. I programmatically added a UIButton and connected it to an IBAction.

All fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which tutorial you are using, but I can say that the solution provided here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk should handle this issue with little complication.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. The tutorial I'm using is: http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm soooo  close to getting this completed with the above tutorial, that it's hard for me to scrap it and try again. I already have everything done once the user is logged in. The issue I'm having is figuring out how to get my IB elements to display over the above CGRect code.

Comment: I totally understand. I would suggest you retitle your question specifically about displaying an IB element over a CGRect because people may see the current question as a specific Facebook question. However I see that you have solved your problem. Good work. +1